# How do you open the locked door in the whirlpool room?

Tags: borderlands-2

In the Bloodshot Stronghold area, there is a whirlpool room.  To your immediate left as you enter the room there is a locked door.

How do you open the door?

Possible spoiler in the image of the door (my current quest) and my current progress in the spoiler tag below.

> I have gone through the stronghold and Roland was just taken away. I defeated the robots in the immediate area that aggro'd me but I did not enter that last section.  I backtracked to here thinking it may have opened it, but nadda.  I also opened the cell doors and turned off the electricity in front of the one chest.

[image: img]

In the image above you see the path you walk down to stand in front of the whirlpool and the door on the left (as you face the whirlpool)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a side quest you can do for Tannis called [Splinter Group](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Splinter_Group). It involves you taking out a group of mutants in the sewers. You cannot open that door before killing them, as their area is locked until you can convince them to open it during the side quest. At the end of their little area is a ladder. It leads up to that door. That's the only way to open it.

On the plus side, XP and two weapons chests!

Comment: Thanks!  I was just exploring that last section and found a little corner that revealed a large section of the map that was sealed off to me...I came back to mention that and saw you already answered :)

Comment: Lovely quest, that one :)

Comment: And spoiler: To get the NPC with loot at that mission, click 2 times TV, 2 times wheel, and once the floor lever. Then Quit and continue, run back and loot again. Over and over untill you get bored.

Comment: The bonus one, at least. And I just did the order listed on the wiki: lever, switch, TV, valve. Then repeated it until he turned up. It works eventually...